# jQuery pulse effect issue

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to get a pulse effect on an image. In [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VwxSh/), I hope to get a light purple border fading in and out around the red circle. The red circle should remain static. I can get both of them to fade in and out, but not just the purple border. Any ideas, please?

**HTML**

```
<div id="pulseDiv">
  <div class="imgNoPulse"><img src="http://ubuntuone.com/1djVfYlV62ORxB8gSSA4R4">
    <div class="imgPulse"><img src="http://ubuntuone.com/2DuAHohinZ7LETkwlSIpM5"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.imgNoPulse { position:absolute;left:15px;top:15px;z-index:1; }
.imgPulse { position:absolute;left:-15px;top:-15px;z-index:-1; }
```

**Javascript**

```
  function fadeThemIn(){
        $('#pulseDiv').children('div').delay(400).fadeIn('slow',function(){fadeThemOut();});
  };
  function fadeThemOut(){
        $('#pulseDiv').children('div').delay(400).fadeOut('slow',function(){fadeThemIn();});
  };
  $(document).ready(function(){
        fadeThemIn();
  });
```

Comment: Wait, so you want the red circle to remain solid all the time, but the purple circle to pulse, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
$('#pulseDiv').children('div')
```

to:

```
$('#pulseDiv').find('div.imgPulse')
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/VwxSh/4/)**

`.children()` only traverses down one level in the DOM while `.find()` will dig down multiple levels. Also you wanted to specify the .imgPulse div, not all divs.

Answer (score 2):

The `<div>` that contains the border is inside of the div that contains the red circle.  You can just use a different selector.

```
$('#pulseDiv').find('div div').delay(400).fadeIn('slow',function(){fadeThemOut();});
```

You could also use a more specific selector like a class.

http://jsfiddle.net/VwxSh/6/

Comment: Thank you Explosion Pills for a different take on the problem which works well, have upvoted this.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/VwxSh/7/

try this buddy

```
  function fadeThemIn(){
        $('.imgPulse').fadeIn('slow',function(){fadeThemOut();});
  };
  function fadeThemOut(){
        $('.imgPulse').fadeOut('slow',function(){fadeThemIn();});
  };
  $(document).ready(function(){
        fadeThemIn();
  });
```

Comment: Another great answer, I lucked out on this question, thank you all. Have upvoted it.

Answer (score 2):

Make your jQuery this:
This targets just the purple circle

```
 function fadeThemIn(){
            $('#pulseDiv .imgPulse').delay(400).fadeIn('slow',function(){fadeThemOut();});
      };
      function fadeThemOut(){
            $('#pulseDiv .imgPulse').delay(400).fadeOut('slow',function(){fadeThemIn();});
      };
      $(document).ready(function(){
            fadeThemIn();
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  function fadeThemIn(){
        $('#pulseDiv').find('.imgPulse').delay(400).fadeIn('slow',function(){fadeThemOut();});
  };
  function fadeThemOut(){
        $('#pulseDiv').find('.imgPulse').delay(400).fadeOut('slow',function(){fadeThemIn();});
  };
  $(document).ready(function(){
        fadeThemIn();
  });
```

[View Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zfBEd/)

Comment: Thank you Valery, have upvoted your answer as it's the same as j08691's except his was provided first.

Answer (score 1):

The fade you're applying to `pulseDiv` also apply to childrens elements, `imgNoPulse` included.

Here's a working jsFiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/VwxSh/3/